# ReactJS <select> with case insensitive value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Normally I would build the following ReactJS component using the `selected` option from the `<option>` HTML tag:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Caller extends Component {
    render = () => {
        return <Test filter={"item2"} />;
    };
}

class Test extends Component {
    render = () => {
        let data = [
            {
                key: "Item1",
                value: "Item1"
            },
            {
                key: "Item2",
                value: "Item2"
            },
            {
                key: "Item3",
                value: "Item3"
            }
        ];

        let options = [];

        data.map(item => {

            let selected = this.props.filter.toLowerCase() === item.key.toLowerCase();

            options.push(
                <option selected={selected} value={item.value}>{item.key}</option>
                );
        });

        return (
            <select>
                {options}
            </select>
        );
    };
}

export default Caller;
```

ReactJS complains about that with the following warning:

```
Warning: Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on <select> instead of setting `selected` on <option>.
```

I know how to use the `value` property from `<select>` on ReactJs, but this will make my component case sensitive, what I don´t want to.

How to properly follow the ReactJS `value` rule with case insensitive data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have both `key` and `value`, and you display the `key`, use `value` as the `props.filter`, and you can be strict on the letters case:

```js
const data = [
  {
      key: "Item1",
      value: "Item1"
  },
  {
      key: "Item2",
      value: "Item2"
  },
  {
      key: "Item3",
      value: "Item3"
  }
];

class Test extends React.Component {  
  render() {
      return (
          <select defaultValue={this.props.filter}>
              {data.map(item => (
                <option value={item.value}>{item.key}</option>
              ))}
          </select>
      );
  };
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Test filter="Item2" />,
  demo
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

If you can't be strict about the `value` as well, you can use [Array#find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the `value` for the case insensitive `key`, and set it as the `value`/`defaultValue` attribute if you want controlled/uncontrolled component:

```js
const data = [
  {
      key: "Item1",
      value: "Item1"
  },
  {
      key: "Item2",
      value: "Item2"
  },
  {
      key: "Item3",
      value: "Item3"
  }
];

class Test extends React.Component {  
  render() {
    const pattern = new RegExp(`^${this.props.filter}$`, 'i');
    const selected = (data.find((item) => pattern.test(item.key)) || {}).value;

    return (
        <select defaultValue={selected}>
            {data.map(item => (
              <option value={item.value}>{item.key}</option>
            ))}
        </select>
    );
  };
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Test filter="item2" />,
  demo
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```